# Android - Button changes backgroundimage for new activity

Tags: java, android, image, button, background

I want my Button to open a new activity using an intent.
This I already implemented and it works.

My problem is setting the background image for this new activity.

For example:

- When button1 got pressed the new activity opens with image1 as
  background.
- When button2 got pressed the new activity opens with image2 as
  background.

Would be very nice if someone would know the Java code to implement this feature or where I could find it.

Comment: Pass unique value with each button click with intent to know which button is pressed.

Comment: Pass the bundle value from your activity to second activity. In second activity get that bundle and take decision according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Call the below function on both button click and pass the value for button1 = 1 and button2 = 2.

```
/*
 *  Button 1 press then pass = 1
 *  Button 2 press then pass = 2
 * */
private void buttonPressed(int value)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("BUTTON_PRESSED", value);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now in your second Activity just get the value from Intent.

```
int whichButtonPressed = getIntent().getIntExtra("BUTTON_PRESSED", 0);

if (whichButtonPressed == 1)
{
    // Show image 1
}
else if (whichButtonPressed == 2)
{
    // Show Image 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send value using **`Intent`** to your next activity using

```
intent.putExtra("button","button1");
```

on button click. Then get the value on another activity using

```
String msg  = intent.getStringExtra("button");
```

and then, perform action by checking value.

**Sample**

**On button1 click**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("button","button1");
startActivity(intent);
```

**On button2 click**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("button","button2");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, In your **SecondActivity onCreate()** method

```
String msg  = intent.getStringExtra("button");

if (msg.equals("button1"))
{
    //yourlayout.setImageBacground(image1);
}
else 
{
    //yourlayout.setImageBacground(image2);
}
```